# Rear ended, metal bumper guard(?) bent

Tags: bumper

I was rear ended at the beginning of February, twice in the same accident. Doesn’t look like much cosmetic damage but we lifted the trunk today and noticed the metal bar behind the bumper is almost V shaped now. My trunk lid is bent inward and we were scared to try to open for fear it may not close again but we tried today and was able to get it closed back. How serious is this? [image]

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you consider "serious"? The part you are worried about is called the bumper reinforcement. The real problem lies in whether you might get hit again. As it stands right now, it appears there is minimal damage to the main part of the car. Another hit and there will be major damage.

It is actually pretty easy to change out. Other than getting the bumper cover off, it's probably six bolts total to remove it. If you feel froggy, you might try getting one from a wrecking yard and replace it yourself.